# How do I show that an angle is a certain value in a triangle with two sides given?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In the following example I am told that angle x is 60° and that I have to prove it is (without a calculator). What is the simplest way of showing that it is true?

[image: Angle x = 60, adjacent = 4 * root 3 - 5, opposite = 12 - 5 * root 3]

Comment: you need to show tan(x) = $\sqrt 3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$12-5\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{3}*(4\sqrt{3}-5)$

Comment: Very nice, succinct hint. +1

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could avoid trigonometry completely, by using a calculator and Pythagoras to calculate the numerical value of the length of the hypotenuse and of the side adjacent to the angle x.